# How to prefix cell with 0, dependant on character length

Tags: vba, excel

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)    
If Len(Target) = 8 Then  
Exit Sub  
End If  
If Range("AF1:AF1000").Value = "Q" Then  
Exit Sub  
End If  
On Error Resume Next  
Application.EnableEvents = False  
If Target.Column = 30 Then  
lTarget = Len(Target)  
Target.NumberFormat = "@"  
For i = 1 To 8 - lTarget  
Target.Value = "0" & Target.Value  
Next  
End If  
Application.EnableEvents = True  
End Sub
```

I'm trying to get this to basically when putting the information into a certain cell, if you put any less that 8 digits in, it will prefix it with '0 until it is 8 which is does, but now i want to adapt it so that it doesn't do it if a certain cell has the text "Q" in it, its not working when i do this how ever, little help?

EDIT: to make this easier the whole AF thing... its the entire AF column not just 1 to 1000 so how do i change that with what i have so far... probably need to re-write the whole thing..lol :(

Comment: Use this instead of the loop: `Target.Value = Right("00000000" & CStr(Target.Value), 8)` . That is, prepend 8 zeroes and keep the 8 rightmost characters. Just be sure that the value will never need more than 8 places!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean it should check column AF **on the same row** for a Q, try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rCell                 As Range

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Columns(30)) Is Nothing Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each rCell In Intersect(Target, Me.Columns(30)).Cells
            Select Case Len(rCell.Value)
                Case 0, 8
                    ' ignore if 8 characters or blank
                Case Else
                    If Strings.UCase$(Cells(rCell.Row, "AF").Value) <> "Q" Then
                        rCell.NumberFormat = "@"
                        rCell.Value = VBA.Right$("0000000" & rCell.Value, 8)
                    End If
            End Select
        Next rCell
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You my friend, are freaking awesome.